# How do I connect to a mysql server on AWS EC2 with a Java Applet?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, applet, amazon-ec2

I am currently trying to get a Java Applet to connect to a MySQL server. I have tested the MySQL server and verified that it works (I can connect with php). However, I can't seem to get my applet to connect.

Right now, I'm testing with Eclipse, and I have the following code listed below (which is NOT my own... just trying to get a connection at the moment).

However, it gives me a Communications Link Failure, and can't connect. Can someone please walk me through how to establish a connection on EC2? I'm new with both EC2 and Java-MySQL connections, and I'm not sure if the problem is with my code, my port configurations, or my Eclipse. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class HelloWorld extends JApplet
{
  // The JDBC Connector Class.
  private static final String dbClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

  private static final String CONNECTION =
                      "jdbc:mysql://<IP of EC2>";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws
                         ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
  {
    System.out.println(dbClassName);
    // Class.forName(xxx) loads the jdbc classes and
    // creates a drivermanager class factory
    Class.forName(dbClassName);

    // Properties for user and password.
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("user","<username>");
    p.put("password","<password>");

    // Now try to connect
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION,p);

    System.out.println("It works !");

    c.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your EC2 security groups allow traffic from your test machine to port 3306?

Comment: That seems to have done the trick... thanks!

Comment: @ceejayoz you should put this in an answer and collect the points :)

Comment: @ceejayoz ditto to what Grzegorz said :)

Answer (score 0):

(It's been two years.  This needs to be removed from Unanswered -- see Comments for the Resolution.)